# Android volley not running inside of onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

I am working on a movie app where i request a JSON object and set the text inside of a textfield. I dont have any errors and it seems like the request never starts. (((I feel like I have tried everything, but i am still a complete noob compared to the pro's here :)

Here is my Gradle files.

Here is my listener

```
yesBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        //Lag string builder


            JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                            try {
                                String title = response.getString("Title");
                            System.out.println("It tries");
                            String year = response.getString("Year");
                            String rated = response.getString("Rated");
                            String released = response.getString("Released");
                            String genre = response.getString("Genre");
                            String director = response.getString("Director");
                            String actors = response.getString("Actors");
                            String plot = response.getString("Plot");
                            String language = response.getString("Language");
                            String awards = response.getString("Awards");
                            //String poster = response.getString("Title");
                            String imdbRating = response.getString("imdbRating");
                            String type = response.getString("Type");

                                movieTitle.setText(response.getString("Title"));
                                System.out.println("Tittel response: " + response.getString("Title"));

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }

            );

            }
        }
    );
```

I could not make a code block with my grade settings but i am on the newest SDK, have compiled volley.

ALSO! I have two other buttons under this listener and they work for testing.

Comment: You need to run the request so add this (AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest );) after the first ();)  -- all you created there is a request but it doesnt run by itself, you need that line of code to run it and it has to be outside the request

Comment: Thanks that worked for me!